# what is the difference between a Git-merge and Git-cherry-pick for a specific commit?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

Is there a difference between a :
`git merge <commit-id>` and `git cherry-pick <commit-id>` ?
where ''commit-id'' is hash of the commit from my new branch that I want to get into master branch.

Comment: Note that you can cherry-pick a *range* of commits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309. You cannot do that with `git merge`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cherry-pick` takes exactly one commit into your current branch.
`merge` takes the entire branch (might be several commits) and merge it to your branch.

Same if you merge it with `<commit-id>` - it doesn't take only the specific commit but the below commits (if there's any) as well.

Answer (score 38):

There is a huge difference in all but trivial cases (and even in trivial cases, there is still a difference).  To understand this properly is a bit of a challenge, but once you do, you're well on your way to really understanding Git itself.

The TL;DR is mostly what [ItayB already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972713/1256452): cherry-pick means to *copy* some existing commit.  The essence of this copying is to turn the commit into a change-set, then re-apply that same change-set to some other existing commit to make a new commit.  The new commit "does the same change" as the commit you have copied, but applies that change to a different snapshot.

This description is useful and practical, but not 100% accurate—it doesn't help if you get *merge conflicts* during your cherry-pick.  As those imply, cherry-pick is internally implemented as a special kind of merging.  If there are no merge conflicts, you don't need to know this.  If you are, well, it's probably best to start with a proper understanding of `git merge` style merging.

Merging (as done by `git merge`) is more complicated: it doesn't ***copy*** anything.  Instead, it makes a new commit of type *merge*, which ... well, does something complicated. :-)  It cannot be explained adequately without first describing the Git *commit graph*.  It also has two parts, which I like to refer to as, first, *merge as a verb* (the action of combining changes), and second, the commit-of-type-merge, or *merge as a noun or adjective:* Git calls these *a merge* or *a merge commit*.

When cherry-pick does merging, it only does the first half, the *merge as a verb* action, and it does it a bit weirdly.  If the merge fails with a conflict, the results can be very puzzling.  They can only be explained by knowing how Git does the *merge as a verb* process.

There is also something Git calls a *fast-forward* operation, or sometimes a *fast-forward merge*, which is not a merge at all.  This, unfortunately, is also confusing; let's hold off on that.

## Everything below is the long answer: read only if you want to understand (more of) Git

#### What to know about commits

The first thing to know—you might already—is that Git is mainly about commits, and each Git commit saves a full snapshot of *every* file.  That is, Git's commits are *not* change-sets.  If you modify one file—say, `README.md`—and make a new commit with that, the new commit has *every* file, in full, including (the full text of) the modified `README.md`.  When you *inspect* the commit, using `git show` or `git log -p`, Git will show you what you changed, but it does that by extracting the *previous* commit's saved files first, then the commit's saved files, and then *comparing* the two snapshots.  Since only `README.md` *changed*, it only shows you `README.md`, and even then, only shows you the difference—the set of changes to the one file.

This, in turn, means that every commit knows its immediate ancestor, or *parent* commit.  Commits, in Git, have a fixed, permanent "true name" that always means *that particular commit*.  This true name, or *hash ID* or sometimes *OID* (the "O" stands for Object), is the big ugly string of letters and digits that Git prints in `git log` output.  For example, `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7` is a commit in the Git repository for Git.  These things look random (though they're not), and are not generally useful to humans, but they are how Git *finds* each commit.  That particular commit has one parent—some other big ugly hash ID—and Git saves the parent's hash inside the commit, so that Git can use the commit to look backwards to its parent.

The result is that if we have a series of commits, they form a backwards-looking chain.  We—or Git—will start at the *end* of this chain and work backwards, to find the history in the repository.  Let's imagine we have a tiny repository with just three commits.  Instead of their actual hash IDs, which are too big and ugly to bother with, let's call them commits `A`, `B`, and `C`, and draw them in their parent/child relationships:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Commit `C` is the latest, so it is the child of `B`.  Git has `C` remember `B`'s hash ID, so we say that `C` *points to* `B`.  When we made `B`, there was only one previous commit, `A`, so `A` is `B`'s parent and `B` points to `A`.  Commit `A` is kind of a special case: when we made it, there were *no* commits.  It has no parent, and this is what allows Git to stop chasing backwards.

Commits are also completely, totally, 100% read-only: once made, nothing about any commit can ever be changed.  This is because the hash ID is actually a cryptographic checksum of the complete contents of the commit.  Change even a single bit, anywhere, and you get a new, different hash ID—a new, different commit.  So a commit snapshot saves the state of your files forever—or at least, for as long as the commit itself continues to exist.  (You can initially think of this as "forever"; the mechanisms for *forgetting* or *replacing* a commit are more advanced, and get quite tricky when it's not the *latest* commit.)

This read-only quality means we can draw the string of commits more simply as:

```
A--B--C
```

and just remember that the linkages go only one way, backwards.  The parent can't know its children because the children don't exist when the parent is born, and once the parent is born, it's frozen for all time.  The child can know its parent, though, because the child is born after the parent exists and is frozen.

#### What to know about branch names

It's easy, in simplified diagrams like the one above, to tell which commit is the *latest*.  The letter `C` come after `B`, after all, so `C` is the latest.  But Git hash IDs look totally random, and Git *needs* the actual hash ID.  So what Git does here is to *store* the hash ID of the *latest* commit in a *branch name*.

In fact, this is the very definition of a branch name: a name like `master` simply stores the hash ID of the commit we want to call the *latest for that branch*.  So given the `A--B--C` string of commits, we just add the name `master`, pointing to commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

What's special about a branch name is that, unlike commits, they *change*.  They not only change, they do it *automatically*.  The process of making a *new* commit, in Git, consists of writing out the commit's contents—its parent hash ID, author/committer information, saved snapshot, log message, and so on—which computes the new hash ID for the new commit, and then *changing the branch name* to record the new commit's hash ID.  If we create a new commit `D` on `master`, Git does that by writing out `D` pointing back to `C`, then updating `master` to point to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

Suppose we now create a *new* branch name, `develop`.  The new name will *also* point to commit `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- develop, master
```

Let's make a new commit `E` now, whose parent will be `D`:

```
A--B--C--D
          \
           E
```

Which *branch name* should Git update?  Do we want `master` to point to `E`, or do we want `develop` to point to `E`?  The answer to this question lies in the special name `HEAD`.

#### Git's HEAD remembers the branch, and thus the current commit

To remember *which branch we want Git to update*, as well as *which commit we have checked-out right now*, Git has the special name `HEAD`, spelled in all capital letters like this.  (Lowercase works on Windows and MacOS due to a quirk, but does not work on Linux/Unix systems that don't share this quirk, so it's best to use the all-uppercase spelling.  If you don't like typing the word, you can use the symbol `@`, which is a synonym.)  Normally, Git *attaches* the name `HEAD` to one branch name:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

Here, we're on branch `develop`, because that's the one `HEAD` is attached to.  (Note that all four commits are on *both* branches.)  If we now make new commit `E`, Git knows which name to update:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` remains attached to the branch; the branch name itself changes which commit hash ID it remembers; and commit `E` is now the *current commit*.  If we make a new commit now, its parent will be `E`, and Git will update `develop`.  (New commit `E` is *only* on `develop`, while commits `A-B-C-D` are still on *both* branches!)

A *detached HEAD* just means that Git has made the name `HEAD` point *directly to some commit* instead of attaching it to a branch name.  In this case, `HEAD` still names the current commit.  You're just not on *any* branch.  Making a new commit still creates the commit as usual, but then instead of writing the new commit's new hash ID into a branch name, Git just writes it directly into the name `HEAD`.

(Detached HEAD is normal, but a little bit special-case; you won't use it for everyday development, except when doing some `git rebase` operations.  You mostly use it for examining historic commits—those not at the tip of some branch name.  We'll ignore it here.)

#### The commit graph, and `git merge`

So now that we know how commits link and how branch names point to the *last* commit on their branch, let's look at how `git merge` works.

Suppose we've made some commits on both `master` and `develop` so that we have a graph that looks like this now:

```
       G--H   <-- master
      /
...--D
      \
       E--F   <-- develop
```

We'll `git checkout master` so that `HEAD` gets attached to `master` pointing to `H`, and then run `git merge develop`.

Git will, at this point, follow *both* chains backwards.  That is, it will start at `H` and work backwards to `G` and then to `D`.  It will also start at `F` and work backwards to `E` and then to `D`.  At this point, Git has found a *shared commit*—a commit that's on *both* branches.  All earlier commits are also shared, but this is the *best* one, because it's the closest commit to both branch tips.

This *best shared commit* is called the *merge base*.  So in this case, `D` is the merge base of `master` (`H`) and `develop` (`F`).  **The merge base commit is determined entirely by the commit graph,** starting from the current commit (`HEAD` = `master` = commit `H`) and from the other commit you name on the command line (`develop` = commit `F`).  The only use of the branch *names* in this process is locating the commits—everything after that depends on the graph.

Having found the merge base, what `git merge` does now is to *combine changes*.  Remember, though, that we said commits are snapshots, not change-sets.  So to *find* changes, Git has to start by extracting the merge base commit itself, into a temporary area.

Now that Git has the merge base extracted, a `git diff` will find what *we* changed, on `master`: the difference between the snapshot in `D` and the snapshot in `HEAD` (`H`).  That's the first change-set.

Git now has to run a second `git diff`, to find what *they* changed, on `develop`: the difference between the snapshot in `D` and the snapshot in `F`.  That's the second change-set.

Hence, what `git merge` does, having located the merge base, is run these two `git diff` commands:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-H>    # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-F>    # what they changed
```

Git then combines these two sets of changes, applies the combined changes to what's in the snapshot in `D` (the merge base), and makes a new commit from the result.  Or rather, it does all of this *as long as the combining works*—or more accurately, as long as *Git thinks the combining worked*.

For now, let's assume that Git thinks it works.  We'll come back to merge conflicts in a moment.

The result of committing the combined changes, applied to the merge base, is a new commit.  This new commit has one special feature: besides saving a full snapshot as usual, it has not one but *two* parent commits.  The *first* of these two parents is the commit that you were on when you ran `git merge`, and the second is the other commit.  That is, the new commit `I` is a *merge commit:*

```
       G--H
      /    \
...--D      I   <-- master (HEAD)
      \    /
       E--F   <-- develop
```

Because the history in a Git repository *is* the set of commits, this makes one new commit whose history is *both* branches.  From `I`, Git can work backwards to `H` *and* to `F`, and from those, to `G` and `E` respectively, and from there, to `D`.  The name `master` now points to `I`.  The name `develop` is unchanged: it continues to point to `F`.

It's now safe to *delete* the name `develop`, if we wish, because we (and Git) can find commit `F` from commit `I`.  Alternatively, we can keep developing on it, making more new commits:

```
       G--H
      /    \
...--D      I   <-- master
      \    /
       E--F--J--K--L   <-- develop
```

If we now `git checkout master` *again* and run `git merge develop` *again*, Git will do the same thing it did before: find a merge base, run two `git diff`s, and commit the result.  The interesting thing now is that because of commit `I`, the merge base is no longer `D`.

Can you name the merge base?  Try it, as an exercise: start at `L` and work backwards, listing the commits.  (Remember to only go *backwards:* from `F`, you can't get to `I`, because that's the wrong direction.  You *can* get to `E`, which is the right way, backwards.)  Then start at `I` and work backwards to both `F` and `H`.  Is one of those in the listing you made for `develop`?  If so, that's the *merge base* (`F`, namely) for the new merge, so Git will use that for its two `git diff` commands.

In the end, if the merge works, we'll get a new merge commit `M` on `master`:

```
       G--H
      /    \
...--D      I--------M   <-- master (HEAD)
      \    /        /
       E--F--J--K--L   <-- develop
```

and a future merge, if we add more commits to `develop`, will use `L` as the merge base.

#### Cherry-picking uses the merge machinery—the two diffs—with a weird base

Let's go back to this state, and attach `HEAD` to `master`:

```
       G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
      /
...--D
      \
       E--F   <-- develop
```

Now let's see how Git actually implements `git cherry-pick develop`.

First, Git resolves the name `develop` to a commit hash ID.  Since `develop` points to `F`, that's commit `F`.

Commit `F` is a snapshot, and has to be turned into a change-set.  Git does this with `git diff <hash-of-E> <hash-of-F>`.

Git *could*, at this point, just apply these same changes to the snapshot in `H`.  That's what our high level, not-quite-accurate description claimed: we just take this diff and apply it to `H`.  And in most cases, what happens *looks like* Git did just that—and in very old versions of Git (that no one uses any more), Git really *did* do that.  But there are cases where it doesn't work right, so Git now performs a weird kind of merge.

In a normal merge, Git would find the merge base and run two diffs.  In the cherry-pick kind of merge, Git just *forces* the merge base to be the parent of the commit being cherry-picked.  That is, since we're cherry-picking `F`, Git forces the merge base to be commit `E`.

Git now does `git diff --find-renames <hash-of-E> <hash-of-H>` to see what *we* changed, and `git diff --find-renames <hash-of-E> <hash-of-F>` to see what *they* (commit `F`) changed.  Then it combines the two sets of changes and applies the result to the snapshot in `E`.  This keeps your work (because whatever you changed, you still have changed) while adding the change-set from `F` too.

If all goes well, which it often does, Git makes a new commit, but this new commit is an ordinary, single-parent commit that goes on `master`.  It's a lot like `F`, and in fact, Git copies the log message from `F` too, so let's call this new commit `F'` to remember that:

```
       G--H--F'   <-- master (HEAD)
      /
...--D
      \
       E--F   <-- develop
```

Note that, just as before, `develop` has not moved.  However, we also have not made a *merge commit:* the new `F'` does not record `F` itself.  The graph is *not* merged; the *merge base* of `F'` and `F` is still commit `D`.

#### This is thus the complete and accurate answer

This is the full difference between a cherry-pick and a true merge: the cherry-pick uses Git's merge machinery to do the change-combining, but leaves the *graph* unmerged, simply making a copy of some existing commit.  The two change-sets used in the combining are based on the cherry-picked commit's parent, not a computed merge base.  The new copy has a new hash ID, not obviously related to the original commit in any way.  The histories found by starting at either branch name, `master` or `develop` here, still join up well into the past.  With a true merge, the new commit is a two-parent merge, and the histories are firmly joined—and of course, the two sets of changes that `git merge` combines are formed from the computed merge base, so they are different change-sets.

#### When the merge fails with a conflict

Git's merge machinery, the engine that combines two different sets of changes, can and does fail to do the combining, sometimes.  This happens when, in the two change-sets, both try to change the *same* lines of the *same file*.

Suppose Git is combining changes, and change-set `--ours` says *touch line 17 of file A, line 30 of file B, and lines 3-6 of file D*.  Meanwhile change-set `--theirs` says nothing about file A, but does say *change line 30 of file B, line 12 of file C, and lines 10-15 of file D.*

Since only ours touches file A, and only theirs touches file C, Git can just use our version of A and their version of C.  We both touch file D, but ours touches line 3-6 and theirs touches lines 10-15, so Git can take both changes to file D.  File B is the real problem: we both touched line 30.

If we made the *same* change to line 30, Git can resolve this: it just takes one copy of the change.  But if we made *different* changes to line 30, Git will stop with a merge conflict.

At this point, Git's *index* (which I have not been talking about here) becomes crucial.  I'm going to continue not talking about it, except to say that Git leaves *all three versions of the conflicted file in it*.  Meanwhile, there's a work-tree copy of file B as well, and in the work-tree file, Git writes its best effort at combining the changes, using conflict markers to show where the problem is.

Your job, as the human running Git, is to resolve each conflict, in any way you like.  Having fixed up all the conflicts, you then use `git add` to update Git's index for the new commit.  Then you can run either `git merge --continue` or `git cherry-pick --continue`, depending on what caused the problem, to have Git commit the result—or, you can run `git commit`, which is the old way of doing this same thing.  In fact, the `--continue` operations mainly just run `git commit` for you: the commit code checks to see if there was a conflict that it should finish, and if so, makes either a regular (cherry-pick) commit or a merge commit.

#### A special case: merge as fast-forward

When you run `git merge othercommit`, Git locates the merge base as usual, but sometimes the merge base is pretty trivial.  Consider, for instance, a graph like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
            \
             I--J   <-- feature-X
```

If you run `git merge feature-X` now, Git finds the merge base by starting at commits `J` and `H` and doing the usual backwards-walking to find the first *shared* commit.  But that first shared commit is commit `H` itself, right where `develop` points.

It's possible for Git to do a real merge, running:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-H>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what they changed
```

and you *can* force Git to do this, using `git merge --no-ff`.  But obviously, diffing a commit against itself will show *no changes at all*.  The `--ours` part of the two sets of changes will be empty.  The result of the merge will just be the same snapshot that is in commit `J`, so if we force a true merge:

```
...--F--G--H------J'   <-- develop (HEAD)
            \    /
             I--J   <-- feature-X
```

then `J'` and `J` will also match.  They will be different commits—`J'` will be a merge commit, with our name and the date and whatever log message we like—but their *snapshots* will be identical.

If we *don't* force a true merge, Git realizes that `J'` and `J` will match like this, and *simply doesn't bother making a new commit*.  Instead, it "slides the name to which HEAD is attached forwards", against the backwards-pointing internal arrows:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I--J   <-- develop (HEAD), feature-X
```

(after which there's no point in drawing the kink in the graph).  That's a *fast-forward operation* or, in Git's rather peculiar terminology, a *fast-forward merge* (even though there's no actual merging!).

Comment: @DrBeco that, sir, was a very elaborate answer. I have [here a related but a more specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65264280/4305171) that I can't derive an answer to from you elaboration. Would you mind to share your wisdom on that question as well? Thank you!

Comment: Dear @zor-el, I only edited some minor details. Full credit to torek.

Comment: Great answer. I have so many concepts clarified. Could you perhaps elaborate on what happens when there is a merge conflict during cherry-pick operation? How would the graph look like?

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown: unlike a real merge, the final result of a cherry-pick operation is just an ordinary (single-parent) commit at the tip of the current branch. So there's no effect on the *graph* and hence no future effect on a merge base. Any conflicts, resolved or not, are irrelevant here: in the end, we just have a snapshot with a single parent.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem, as Dr Beco says, that the merge process itself is the same for both merge and cherry-pick, though as he notes the bases and other aspects are different. I think there is an argument that the way the merge is performed, i.e. the rules of the merge, should be different for merge and cherry-pick and we presented a paper on this at XML Prague this year "Merge and Graft: Two Twins That Need To Grow Apart" http://www.xmlprague.cz/day2-2019/#merge which may be of interest.