# What's the difference between git merge --squash A SINGLE COMMIT and git cherry-pick that same commit?

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand the practical distinction between cherry-picking and squash-merging *a single commit*, if there is any. To be more precise, give the following simple situation:

```
-O <- master
  \
   A <- develop
```

Is there a practical difference between cherry-picking and squash-merging the *single commit* A into master?

A lot of answers here focus on the general difference when develop is several commits ahead of master (where the distinction is clear that cherry-picking processes a single commit and squash-merging process all commits back to a common ancestor).

What I'm trying to understand though is, is there any reason to prefer squash commit in this particular situation over the IMO easier performed cherry-pick?

Or maybe to make it more general, in the situation where develop is merely ahead of master (i.e. where fast-forwarding would be possible):

```
-O <- master
  \
   A-B-C <- develop
```

Is there a difference between cherry-picking A, B, and C (in that order) and then squashing them on master and the `git merge --squash` -> resolve conflicts -> `git commit` sequence?

My observation so far is that squash-merging often reports merge conflicts for the simplest change where cherry-picking doesn't. For example this trivial change in A (from O) is reported as merge conflict when squash-merging but not with cherry-picking:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
        allow(subject).to receive(:some_method).and_return(some_result)
=======
        allow(controller).to receive(:some_method).and_return(some_result)
>>>>>>> 3s/checkout-page/develop
```

After resolving the conflicts the state of the working director is the same of course.

It seems cherry-picking is easier and less problematic in the short term, but I'm wondering if there are consequences down the road.

Comment: If you do both, what differences can you observe?

Comment: I don't observe a difference in the immediate outcome, but sometimes squash-merging reports conflicts that cherry-picking doesn't, so there's a processing difference, and that sort of also makes me wonder about possible consequences down the line.

Comment: You may want to add that and, instead of paraphrasing, the actual code you ran to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: I recommend setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`, so that when you do get a conflict, you see what was in the merge base commit, as well as what was in the diff from the merge base to `HEAD` and what was in the diff from the merge base to their commit. In this case that might show you that the commit you thought was the merge base, is not actually the merge base.

Comment: A silly note :if you have `rerere` enabled, conflicts solved the first time will be automatically resolved the second time. Check your git config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default commit messages will differ.

Other than that, if the commit graph is what you've drawn here:

```
...--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             K   <-- develop
```

the effect of merge or cherry-pick will be the same, because the actual merge base of `master` and `develop` is commit `J`.  To see this in action, use `git rev-parse` and `git merge-base`:

```
$ git rev-parse master
<some hash ID appears>
$ git rev-parse develop
<another hash ID appears>
$ git merge-base --all master develop
<the hash ID from the rev-parse master command appears again>
```

This merge or cherry-pick will never have any conflicts.  The reason is that the parent of `K` is `J`, and the current commit is `J`, so the merge-base / cherry-pick-parent *is* the current commit and one of the two diffs is empty.

Now let's suppose that the graph looks like this:

```
...--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       K   <-- develop
```

This time, the merge base will be commit `H`.  The result should again be the same for both operations as the merge base of `master` (the current commit `J`) and `develop`, but this time there could be merge conflicts, as the two sides of a diff will compare `H`-vs-`J` for the "ours" changes and `H`-vs-`K` for the "theirs" changes.  If we and they touched the same lines of the same file, or touched lines that abut in any one file, we'll get a merge conflict.

> A lot of answers here focus on the general difference when develop is several commits ahead of master ...

Right: in this case, we have something more like, say:

```
...--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       K--L   <-- develop
```

Here, cherry-picking commit `L` makes Git do a three-way merge between the contents of `K` (as the merge base), the contents of `J` (as the "ours" commit), and the contents of `L` (as the "theirs" commit).  We therefore diff `K` vs `master` (i.e., `J`) to see what we changed, and `K` vs `L` to see what they changed.  Git then combines these diffs and applies the combined changes to the contents of `K` to produce a cherry-pick `L'`.

By contrast, `git merge --squash` finds commit `H` as the merge base, comparing `H` vs `J` to find our changes, and `H` vs `L` to find theirs.  Git then combines *these* changes—which are probably two different sets of changes than the cherry-pick sets—and applies the combined changes to the snapshot in `H`, rather than to the snapshot in `K`.

Comment: *"the effect of merge or cherry-pick will be the same, because the actual merge base of master and develop is commit J"*

But why does `git merge --squash` sometimes report conflicts where cherry-picking doesn't?

(Thanks, btw, for the quick and elaborate answer.)

Comment: Build a repeatable example, e.g., a little shell script that makes a repository, makes several commits, and sets things up so that this happens. Then we'll be able to repeat it and see if it happens in our own versions of Git, because it definitely should not. :-)

Comment: torek, with your comment to my question above, (*"In this case that might show you that the commit you thought was the merge base, is not actually the merge base"* - and sure enough, that was the case), I consider my question answered. Thanks for the great elaboration!